# Position numpy matrix and arrays when writing in CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am working on Sea Surface Temperature (SST) data and try to write the values in CSV file with `longtitude` and `latitude` values. What I have:

`[512x1024]` numpy data as the temprerature values,

`[512x1]` numpy data as the `latitude` values and,

`[1x1024]` numpy data as the `longtitude` values.

What I want to do create a CSV file:

put the `lontitude` values in the `1st row` starting from the `2nd column`

put the `latitude` values in the `1st column` starting from the `2nd row` and

put the `[512x1024]` temperature matrix starting from `2nd` column and row.

Sorry for not providing any code, but I have been trying all column row selection methods of numpy, pandas, etc. together with `np.savetext()`. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pandas dataframe with `latitude` as the index, `longitude` as the columns, and write to a csv

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(sst, latitude, longitude).to_csv('filename.csv')
```

**Expample**

```
sst = np.ones((5, 5))
latitude = np.arange(5)
longitude = np.arange(5)

print(pd.DataFrame(sst, latitude, longitude).to_csv())

,0,1,2,3,4
0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
2,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
3,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
4,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
```

Comment: That much easy, but perfect. Thanks so much.